# Is it possible to create a motion tween in as2 code

Tags: actionscript, tween, motion

Is it possible to make a motion tween with as2 code only ( not with timeline).  If it is, then can you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the Tween class:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00000350.html

But I believe most ActionScript developers prefer to use the third party libraries TweenNano/TweenLite/TweenMax or Tweener, and that they still support AS2:

http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/

http://code.google.com/p/tweener/